# Problems with alertdialog show in fragment android

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog, fragment

I have followed android example but I have an incomprehensive error :

```
void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(fm, "alert");
}

public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance() {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("test")
                .setMessage("bla bla bla").create();
    }
}
```

`newFragment.show(fm, "alert");` returns me an error :

> The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is
>   not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Someone could help me ?

Answer (score 13):

The problem is because you need to be using the support package's `FragmentManager` but you are using the native `FragmentManager` when you call `getFragmentManager()`. Try calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` when initializing your variable `fm`.

Answer (score 6):

Actually after you do as @Jacob says, you also have to make sure that you include             DialogFragment from the Support package and not from the native package.

You can do that by importing,

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case my `minSDK` is set to `14` so I did not want to use the support package. My problem was I was importing the wrong `DialogFragment` like so:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

I changed it to this and it worked:

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```